# Spring Data JPA CrudRepository Method name to compare columns?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

How do I name a method to find all rows with a condition based on comparing two columns?
For example:

```
public class Example {
    Integer num1;
    Integer num2;
}
```

I want to query for all `Example`s where num1 is less than num2.
What would be the method name?

```
public class ExampleDao extends CrudRepository<Example, Integer> {
    List<Example> ???();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Use a query like this:

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Example t where t.num1 < t.num2") 
List<Example> findNum1IsLessThanNum2();
```

Comment: That isn't a named query, that is just a regular query.

Comment: The equivalent of named query in Spring Data JPA